# How to loop through a va_list if the number of arguments is unknown?

Tags: c

How do I loop through a va_list if the number of additional arguments is unknown?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int add(int x, int y, ...) {
    va_list intargs;
    int temp = 0;

    va_start(intargs, y);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { /* How can I loop through any number of args? */ 
        temp += va_arg(intargs, int);
    }
    va_end(intargs);

    return temp + x + y;
}

int main() {
    printf("The total is %d.\n", add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You will probably need a NULL at the end and look for that.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually the approach I am taking now. I think it's easier than using an arg counter at the start of the call. It's easier to place a NULL at the end.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use a sentinel value as a terminator, e.g `NULL` or `-1`

Comment: What if you want to add 0 or a negative number? `va_arg(intargs, int)` will cast NULL to 0.

Comment: Could you give us an example of that? I'm still confused on how to do it.

Answer (score 24):

You must indicate the number of parameters somehow (if you're writing portable code) when using variable length argument lists. You may be now thinking "But printf doesn't require you to indicate a number of arguments!"

True, however the number can be inferred by first parsing the format strings for % format specifiers.

Comment: 1 because it's probably true. -1 because C++ is such a mess.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to do something like pass the number of arguments as the first parameter.

E.g. see here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdarg/va_start/

And more discussion here: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/714-ellipses-and-why-to-avoid-them/

Variable arguments can be hazardous so if at all possible I'd try to avoid them.  Passing a "vector" type which includes size and a pointer to the element array would be safer.

Comment: Thanks, I am using ANSI C, and I don't think there's any other way to avoid this.

Comment: @Bob: Pass an int* and the size of the array.  The problem with the NULL at the end is at some point someone will forget it and it may become a hard to debug bug.

Answer (score 1):

You use the first argument to indicate the number of elements, and then, you can pass any number of elements to the function.

Here is a typical call:

```
int i = add(5, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60);
```

There are 5 numbers to sum, so the first parameter is **5**. Then the rest are the 5 numbers to add up.

The function would then be:

```
int add(int argc, ...)
{
    int result = 0;
    va_list ptr;
    va_start(ptr, argc);

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        result += va_arg(ptr, int);
    }
    return result;
}
```

**References:**

[va_arg()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_arg/)

[va_start()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_start/?kw=va_start)

[va_list()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_list/?kw=va_list)

Answer (score 1):

The two answers above that suggest adding a first argument to indicate the number of arguments miss the point:  the number of arguments is unknown.

Using a sentinel value (or series of sentinel values) at the end is the only way to solve the problem.