# How to determine if va_list is empty

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, variadic-functions

I have been reading that some compilers support va_list with macros and users were able to [overload the functionality with other macros in order to count the va_list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.std.c/d-6Mj5Lko_s).

With visual studio, is there a way to determine if the va_list is empty (aka count==0)? Basically I would like to know this condition:

```
extern void Foo(const char* psz, ...);
void Test()
{
  Foo("My String"); // No params were passed
}
```

My initial thought was to do something like this:

```
va_list vaStart;
va_list vaEnd;
va_start(vaStart, psz);
va_end(vaEnd);
if (vaStart == vaEnd) ...
```

The problem is that va_end only sets the param to null.

```
#define _crt_va_start(ap,v)  ( ap = (va_list)_ADDRESSOF(v) + _INTSIZEOF(v) )
#define _crt_va_arg(ap,t)    ( *(t *)((ap += _INTSIZEOF(t)) - _INTSIZEOF(t)) )
#define _crt_va_end(ap)      ( ap = (va_list)0 )
```

I was thinking of maybe incorporating a [terminator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800641/how-to-loop-through-a-va-list-if-the-number-of-arguments-is-unknown) but I would want it to be hidden from the caller so that existing code doesnt need to be changed.

Answer (score 8):

There is no way to tell how many arguments are passed through `...`, nor what type they are. Variadic function parameters can only be used if you have some other way (e.g. a `printf`-style format string) to tell the function what to expect; and even then there is no way to validate the arguments.

C++11 provides type-safe variadic templates. I don't know whether your compiler supports these, or whether they would be appropriate for your problem.

Comment: That will result in an ambiguous call to overloaded function :(

Comment: @BabelFish: So it does. I'd thought the non-variadic version would be chosen, but it seems I was wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I'm assuming that "there is no way to tell" applies to Objective-C as well... and I'm not assuming that you'd know, but perhaps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is fairly old, but I thought it might be helpful to flesh it out a bit. As Mike Seymour answered quite correctly, there is no absolutely reliable way to determine the number of arguments in a `va_list`. That's why the conventional way to define a variadic function is to include a parameter that has that information, like so: `void func(const char *str, int count, ...);`, which defines a contract your callers are supposed to abide by.

**EDIT:** The standard (7.16.1.1.3) is actually silent on the value returned by `va_arg(vl, type)` for any call past the end of the variable argument list. The most common case for most types is typed-zero. However, CAVEAT EMPTOR - it doesn't have to be.

The value returned from `va_arg(vl, type)` when there are no more arguments is a typed-zero value. For numeric types, it is 0. For pointers, it is a NULL pointer. For structs, it is a struct with all fields zeroed. If you elect to copy the `va_list` and try to count the copy, like so:

```
void func(const char *str, ...) {
    va_list vl;
    va_list vc;
    int x;
    int count;

    count = 0;
    va_start(vl, str);
    va_copy(vc, vl);
    do {
        x = va_arg(vc, int);
        if (x == 0) break;
        count++;
    } while (1)
    va_end(vc);
    .
    .
    . // do something, or something else,
    . // based on the number of args in the list
    .
    va_end(vl);
```

You would have to make the assumption that the caller would abide by the contract not to pass a NULL or zero value in the list. Either way, you have to understand that the caller of a variadic function is responsible for abiding by the stated contract. So write your function, publish the contract, and sleep easy.

Comment: Where did you find this info? According to cppreference: "If va_arg is called when there are no more arguments in ap, the behavior is undefined." Also, I tried with gcc6 and I didn't get a typed-zero value.

Comment: How variadic arguments are handled is very much dependent on the particular platform's ABI.  The straightforward stack-based approach has absolutely no way to determine the number of arguments; it just walks up the stack reading whatever happens to be there.  In addition to the fact that (as noted) your actual arguments might contain a zero, there's no reason to believe that the stack garbage after your arguments is a zero.  Ref C99 section 7.15.1.1 for the authoritative "behavior is undefined".

Answer (score -3):

I am aware that my answer isn't an "orthodox" answer, however due to the limitation of the [va_list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_list/) macro, I found the following solution to work. We can look at a va_list as an array of chars, and even better, a null terminated one, so you can try

```
va_list argptr;
if(strcmp(argptr,"")) 
{
   // not empty
}
else
{
   // empty
}
```

I tried that and it worked for me.
I used Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. The project type is Win32 Console Application. No compilation errors.

Comment: You should edit your answer to say on what compiler (including version) it works. My GCC 7.2 rejects this code.

Comment: I took the time to build a test program. I used Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. The project type is Win32 Console Application. No compilation errors.

Comment: This won't work. The underlying type of the `va_list` type is often chosen to be a `char*`, because a `char*` can alias any other pointer type. That doesn't make the pointed-to memory a character array. Consider `void foo(int, ...); foo(0, 0);`, and try your proposed solution. The call to [strcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) will exhibit undefined behavior, and probably report an empty list (although it isn't). Sometimes you are more lucky, and trigger an access violation instead.