# How can I write a function that takes a variable number of arguments (integers) and output them using stdargs?

Tags: c, bash

This program accepts a finite amount of integers and outputs them using a macro provided by va_arg. (stdargs)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

 void main()
{
foo(5,3,4);

}

void foo(int i,...){

va_list argp;
va_start(argp,i);
int p;

while ((p = va_arg(argp,int))!= NULL)printf("%d",p);

va_end(argp);
}
```

However although no compiltation/syntax errors arise I do not get the output I want. I get this running on bash:

[image]

**How can I fix my program so I get: 5,3,4?**

Comment: `va_arg()` doesn't magically know when the passed parameters have run out. You need to actually pass `NULL` (or, really, `0` since `va_arg(argp, int)` will never return a pointer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass an explicit last value and stop on that, because `va_arg` is not able to detect the end of the arguments.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int i, ...) {
  va_list argp;
  va_start(argp, i);
  do {
    printf("%d\n", i);
  } while ((i = va_arg(argp, int)) != -1);
  va_end(argp);
}

int main() {
  foo(5, 3, 4, -1);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
5
3
4
```

Comment: I still don't understand why I just can't use '(p = va_arg(argp,int))!= NULL)'. Theoretically it should work

Comment: What makes you think it should "theoretically work" if you never actually pass `NULL`? Even if you do, `int`s are not pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to figure out the number of arguments somehow because `va_arg` does not magically know it. If you're going to be using `NULL` as a [sentinel value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800641/how-to-loop-through-a-va-list-if-the-number-of-arguments-is-unknown), pass `NULL` as the last argument in the list.

```
foo(5,3,4, NULL);
```

Secondly, you're ignoring the first argument, `i`, so it only prints out `34`. If you mean to use `i` as the number of arguments passed, then use a for loop instead.

---

Other minor things:

- `int main()` instead of [void main()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)
- Forward declare `void foo(int i,...);`.

Comment: 5,3,4 are type `int` and `NULL` is a pointer.  Suggest using a  sentinel value that is the same type as `5,3,4`.